# How to "translate" this SQL query to queryset in django

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

So I've got these Django models (the code is simplified by the way):

```
    class Travel(models.Model):
      #there are many other fields
      origin_city = CharField()
      end_city = CharField()

    class Segment(models.Model):
      start_time = DateTimeField()
      origin = CharField()
      end = CharField()
      travel = ForeignKey(Travel)
      price = IntegerField()
```

So a travel has a set of segments, for example if the travel is A->B->C->D->E, then the segments are (A,B) , (B,C) , (C,D) and (D,E). I want to get, given an origin and end, the travels that pass through the given origin and then through the given end. For example, if origin and end are (B,D), the example travel is valid, since it goes through B at some point and then it goes through D later, but it wouldn't be valid for (D,B).

I know that in SQL, this could be done like this (assuming travel stores ids and segment has them with foreign key restrictions):

```
    SELECT t.*
    FROM travel as t, segment as s1,segment as s2
    WHERE t.id = s1.travel_id AND t.id = s2.travel_id
    AND s1.origin = (user given origin)
    AND s2.end = (user given end)
    AND s1.start_time < s2.start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should get you there, with `user_origin` and `user_end` as user-supplied criteria:

```
travels = (Travel.objects
    .filter(segment__origin=user_origin)
    .annotate(origin_time=F('segment__start_time'))
    .filter(segment__end=user_end, segment__start_time__gt=F('origin_time'))
)
```

You grab a reference to the `start_time` of the first join to `Segment`and refer back to it in the second `filter()` that creates a second join to `Segment`.